# How to hide data label with zero value in charts. js

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I have below chart created some results with 0 values I want to hide labels that hold 0 value only. I created it by PHP but I hide the value, not the label itself. for example, I have labels

> ['6/1/2018'.'6/2/2018','6/3/2018', etc ....]

and the label 6/2/2018 hold 0 value I want to hide it

```
var barChartData1 = {
    labels: [
    <?php
    $arraylenght = count($month);
    for($x = 0; $x < $arraylenght; $x++) {
        echo '"' . $month[$x] . '"' . ',' ;
    }
    ?>
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            type: 'line',
            label: 'Nps',
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 1,
            fill: false,
            data: [
                <?php
                foreach ($month  as $date ){
                    $e_t = "select * from nps where date = '$date' and team_id ='$id'"; // to select total rows             
                    $e_p = "select * from nps where team_id= '$id' and nps_rating >= 9 and date = '$date' "; // select promoter
                    $e_d = "select * from nps where team_id ='$id' and nps_rating <= 6 and date = '$date' "; // select dertactor
                    $e_tq = $cont->query($e_t); 
                    $e_pq = $cont->query($e_p); 
                    $e_dq = $cont-> query ($e_d);

                    if ($e_tq->num_rows == 0){
                        $e_eq = 0;
                        //continue;
                    }else{
                        $e_eq = (($e_pq->num_rows - $e_dq->num_rows) / $e_tq->num_rows) * 100 ; // get result of nps
                    }
                        echo round($e_eq) . ',';
                    }
                ?>
                ]
```

Comment: You can google "chart.js callback" and look at the labelling entry. You will have an example at the bottom about how to use the callback. Pretty much you will iterate the list and if the value is `0` then you will return `""` otherwise return `value`. If you don't like that then before creating the chart just do a loop and where your index value is 0, modify the same index of the label array and make it `""`.